# The .NET SDK 4.0 or 4.5 tools could not be found ERROR

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, f#

I'm creating a web api in F# and when try to use the nuget package FSharp.Data.TypeProviders, I get the following error.

The type provider 'FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported an error: Error reading schema. The .Net SDK 4.0 or 4.5 tools could not be found.

The .NET SDK 4.0 and 4.5 are installed, I've checked. I've also retried to reinstall them, but they won't let me, because they're already installed.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2017 a number of times. I've just reinstalled windows 10 and that hasn't fixed the error. I'm all out of ideas.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to install the windows 8 and possibly 8.1 SDKs. Can you give it a try: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-sdk and https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk

Comment: Yep, done that. Still didn't do anything

Comment: Oh. Are you trying to build a type provider or just use one? Can you post some code and be a bit more explicit where the error occurs. I haven't used `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` before, maybe it's some mix up with the FSharp.Core versions. Can you check that as well?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same problem with my F# projects that use TypeProviders. Installing `.NET Framework 4.5 Software Development Kit` from the `Windows 8.0 SDK` is all you need to do.